# D3.js color proportional to the values of an object

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors

i have a Json Tree where each non-leaf node has an object like this

```
    mime_types={
  "application/octet-stream": 1,
  "application/x-executable": 49,
  "application/x-object": 13,
  "application/x-sharedlib": 47,
  "image/gif": 5,
  "image/png": 3,
  "inode/symlink": 4,
  "text/plain": 58
}
```

I would like to map each element with a color and for each node is filled with a color that represents the proportion.
For example: if *"text/plain"* is red (255,0,0) and *"application/octet-stream"* is blue (0,0,255) and the node have only these two keys, the color of this is node is something like (255,0,1)

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON to me.  Don't hash keys need to be quoted in JSON?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller   Yeah, you are right, i just edited the question. The problem still remains ahahah

Comment: What do the numbers with the mime type represent? Is that the weights?   So this object should be colored 58:1 the color of text/plain to application/octet-stream?  Does this mean that this object would have 8 colors mixed together in different proportions?  Where are the colors for these mime types defined?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes, it is the exact thing i want to achieve. The number represents the occurences of the mime in inside a tree. the point is to define such colors